# Formatting slider values with commas

Tags: jquery

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 200000,
  step: 500,
  values: [2500, 25000],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
  }
});
$("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
```

How do I format the outcome: $2,500 - $20,000

Comment: have a look at [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap `$("#slider-range").slider("values", 0)` as a parameter and pass it to function which would take that value and with help of **regular expression** `replace()` method return a new string with matched pattern:

```
function ThousandSeparate(val) {
    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())){
      val = val.toString().replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, '$1'+','+'$2');
    }
    return val;
}
```

Check working code: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p6ga67rh/3/)

Comment: This works when the page loads, but as soon as you move the sliders the commas are no longer there.

Comment: Just call ThousandSeparate function in slide method. I updated my answer, check jsFiddle link

Comment: Thanks so much @t